# Entity Framework 6 migration when chaging from simple type to complex type (table)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I had something like:

```
class Person
  string CarModel
```

which in terms of database got translated to MyClass table with 'MyProperty' string column.

Now I have:

```
class Person
  string CarId

class Car
   int Id
   string Model
```

Which EF translates to two tables: MyClass and MyNewClass, and there is Car.CarId -> pointing to Car.Id. So far so good.

I will manually take care of populating the Car table with the items that were in the Person.CarModel column. But question is: how do I migrate my data? I want the Person.CarId to point to the correct Car.Id record. I am thinking something like:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Person]
SET [CarId] = cars.Id
   FROM [dbo].[Cars] cars
WHERE cars.Model = [dbo].[Cars].CarModel
```

I am doing that between the Adding of the new column (CarId) and the drop of the old column (CarModel) from the table. However, the SQL server complains 'CarId column does not exist'. I guess it has something to do with the change being transactional.

What is the correct approach to this? I am using scripts (i.e. I am deleting my Migrations folder after I generate the .sql out of it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best way is:

1. Remove old `CarModel` string from the model and add new Car entity to your Person, but in migration behind this instead of deleting a `CarModel` column rename it to `[_Stale_CarModel]` (naming is just for example).
2. Run your manual data migration script over the database, verify that data is migrated correctly - ids are set for rows that have `[_Stale_CarModel]` set and values are correct. You can either manually add an EF migration with your data migration code inside, or do it on your own if you need to do verification script for your data before commiting actual migrated data OR if your migration takes more than default timeout.
3. Create a migration for cleaning up your DB schema (EF will create empty migration for this step) and manually write `DropColumn("Person", "[_Stale_CarModel]")`

Comment: Thanks, I based my solution on your post. I've created a total of 3 scripts - initial migration which adds the new table/column, a migration sql script which populates the new column based on the old one and then another migration sql script which drops the old column.